# Sequence terms being divisible

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, divisibility

Here's a question I would like **hints** for:

> The sequence ${x_n}$ is defined by $x_{n+2}=6x_{n+1}-9x_{n}$ for $n \geq 0$ where $x_0=3$ and $x_1=18$. What is the smallest $k$ such that $x_k$ is divisible by $2013$?

I'm not sure how to start this one. I'd like hints rather than a full solution. Also, is there some sort of general technique for approaching such problems?

Comment: This is a solvable difference equation. Perhaps you can solve it and then see what is $x_n$.

Comment: $x_{n+2}=6x_{n+1}-9x_{n}\implies r^2=6r-9\implies r=3$

Comment: Don't think I'm familiar with that, what is this technique called? Solving recursive sequences?

Comment: Yes, you form a characteristic equation. In this case it is $t^2-6t+9=0$. Then $t=3$. The solution is $x_n=3^n(c_1+nc_2)$. You get these constants by plugging in $x_0=3$ and $x_1=18$.

Comment: I think it's $x_n=3^{n+1}(n+1)$.

Comment: And then I basically just find the $n$ for which $c_1 + n c_2$ is divisible by $671$ (since the three is already there)?

Comment: Yes. I think it's $n=670$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation